# Ethics of a BitTorrent Software Proposal in Area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51, stack-exchange, moderation, piracy

I've an interesting question for you all. I was giving some thought to possible site proposals on Area 51, and I had the idea to pose a proposal for a "Torrent Tracker Software and Management" Q&A site.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_tracker):

> A BitTorrent tracker is a server that assists in the communication
> between peers using the BitTorrent protocol. It is also, in the
> absence of extensions to the original protocol, the only major
> critical point, as clients are required to communicate with the
> tracker to initiate downloads. Clients that have already begun
> downloading also communicate with the tracker periodically to
> negotiate with newer peers and provide statistics; however, after the
> initial reception of peer data, peer communication can continue
> without a tracker.

This is a bit of a moral quandry to me. Would such a site be *explicitly* inappropriate for Stack Exchange? A  site about tracker software would not explicitly be about piracy, but it might still be implied.

There have been, in the past, some interesting answers on the subject of piracy here on Stack Exchange:

> With regards to the first question involving
> [Limewire](https://superuser.com/questions/40240/limewire-trojans) I
> have removed and cleaned up the comments and formatted the question.
> However there is nothing wrong with the question directly as the OP
> never refers to downloading illegal software, and I think it received
> a very good answer on top of it. I don't see any reason why the
> question should not be allowed, unless it explicitly **encourages and
> suggest links to illegal software and warez**
> — [Diago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21679/227680)

> Close and flag these types of questions as too localized.
>
> Yes, I know it's a bit of a contradiction.  We do the same with
> copyright infringements; moderators are not equipped to deal with
> copyright claims (copyright claims should be directed at SE Corporate,
> in the form of a DMCA takedown notice), and routinely decline such
> flags.  We do, however, close and delete such posts on the grounds
> that plagiarized content is not a good fit for the site.
>
> Questions that ask for help with cracking someone else's software are
> in violation of Stack Exchange's TOS anyway.  See
> https://stackexchange.com/legal, Section 3(C).
> — [The Grinch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142868/227680)

And:

> The Stack Exchange Terms of Service expressly prohibit
>
> > Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer
> > network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or
> > store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or
> > obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity.
>
> So if the user is asking how to download a pirated copy of Visual
> Studio, or tell others how to do it, as a moderator I would generally
> take action on that.  I also would take action on questions that ask
> us to do something that clearly infringes on the rights of others,
> like asking us to help him hack a specific website.
>
> However, the techniques for programmatically working with a Torrent or
> breaching website security are perfectly acceptable subjects on Stack
> Overflow. There's no way to police how someone uses the knowledge that
> they get here (there are perfectly legitimate uses for that
> information), and no way to know for sure whether they're telling the
> truth about how they're going to use that information anyway.
> — [The Grinch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208629/227680)

And then there's the Stack Exchange [TOS](https://stackexchange.com/legal):

> Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited. Under no circumstances will Subscriber use the Network or the Service to (a) send unsolicited e-mails, bulk mail, spam or other materials to users of the Network or any other individual, (b) harass, threaten, stalk or abuse any person or party, including other users of the Network, (c) create a false identity or to impersonate another person, or (d) knowingly post any false, inaccurate or incomplete material.

It may also be noted that, while torrenting is often associated with piracy, it does have its legal uses. As an example, a variety of Linux distros (including [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)) are freely and legally distributed via BitTorrent by the maintainers of said distros.

In summary, I would like to pose several questions here. They are:

- Is piracy too heavily implied for such a site to find an appropriate home here on Stack Exchange
- Would the risk of such a site outweigh any substantial reward that might be gained (i.e. would the (potential) users of such a site be so inclined towards promotion of piracy that the challenge of moderation would itself outweigh the benefits of the site)
- Are the moderators equipped to handle such a site?
- Is such a site against the Stack Exchange TOS or any other written/unwritten rules here on Stack Exchange.

**Note**: As it stands, I do not believe the scope is large enough or the audience is there for a site proposal. I am merely interested in the ethics here on Stack Exchange. I am neither promoting nor decrying piracy.

**Additional Information**:

As noted by several users, BitTorrent does have its legal uses. While it is sometimes associated with piracy, it is not purely limited to illicit activities.

It may also be interesting to note that there exists, in beta, a [Tor Stack Exchange site](https://tor.stackexchange.com/). While Tor is not associated with piracy, it can , in certain circles, be associated with other illicit activities. That being said, the Tor site has survived into beta and has not acted as, to quote @RobM "a magnet for those who are less scrupulous".

**Edit**: [I've made a proposal on Area 51 related to this question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62649/torrent-tracker-software-and-administration?referrer=hwG23diMH1haC0MbeVv9hg2).

Comment: I have downloaded (**as encouraged by the publisher**) the free community remake of the original half life using bit torrent; bit torrent has legal uses

Comment: @RichardTingle Noted. I completely forgot to mention that.

Comment: I guess the questions might be - regardless of the 'pure' intentions of the site and its initial founders, would it just act as a magnet for those who are less scrupulous? And is the possibility of that a problem that SE doesn't want to have to deal with?

Comment: It's not like SE would host the trackers or anything.  I think excluding questions related to programming just because that knowledge **might** be used to do something illegal isn't a good idea.  I mean, does that mean we should stop mentioning SQL injection, because those answers **might** be used by unscroupulous people?

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore It looks like your proposal was removed. What happened: it didn't receive enough support? I'm asking because I would like to ask a technical question about torrents and I'm looking for a better place to ask it on StackExchange. I've [asked](http://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/21qkr1/i_would_like_to_set_up_a_website_to_share_files/) it on r/torrents on Reddit, but I'm not sure how many if folks there are technical enough for this.

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov The proposal was removed as there wasn't enough interest. Proposals that go a month without activity are culled.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore It's a pity. How much of activity is 'enough' and how much did your proposal get? I'm interested in setting up a torrent site and I'm asking around ([my latest question is here](http://superuser.com/questions/735874/i-would-like-to-set-up-a-website-to-share-files-via-torrents-what-should-i-know)) but I haven't found a place where I would get the information I want. Maybe it's time to try and make the proposal once again?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov I believe the proposal peaked at ten followers before it was removed (perhaps less). Any activity will prevent a proposal's deletion, it just failed to receive any during that time. Even still, each proposal on Area51 is subject to closure after a year if it maintains activity, but fails to reach the commitment phase (no matter how frustratingly close it may be).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you think a Q&A site about "Torrent Tracker Software and Management" would be useful, go ahead and propose it on Area 51.

We can spend all day theorizing & arguing about the kind of questions people might propose there. Why do that when you can just propose the site, and get a much clearer idea of what torrent related questions people are *actually* interested in asking? If, after a while, it becomes obvious that the majority of questions are in some way (legally or ethically) problematic, we can just close the proposal.

Comment: Sidenote: [Stack Exchange is using torrent to distribute its data dumps](http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump).

Comment: Point taken. I've [proposed the site on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/62649/torrent-tracker-software-and-management). Hopefully I'll be able to gather further input as to the ethics of this all there.

Comment: Good luck with the proposal @DanteTheEgregore. People had similar concerns with the Tor proposal, but the majority questions it generated turned out to be very technical in nature and with little (if any) connection to illicit activities.