# Where is the right place for torrent technical discussion?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know how to set up a torrent server on a dedicated server. I think I don't yet underestand all parts that go into this.

Where are such questions appropriate?

I think there was a [StackExchange site proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210790/ethics-of-a-bittorrent-software-proposal-in-area-51) once, but it looks like it has been removed and there's nothing about torrents even in the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) Is this not a legitimate topic for discussion on Stack Exchange or is there zero public interest?

Comment: Setting up such software sounds like it might be on-topic for Super User.

Comment: I had the same idea as Martijn, however looking at the bittorrent tag I only see clients mentioned. ServerFault seems to have more questions on the server side: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent    You could ask this question on meta.serverfault.com to check if they are open for these kind of questions, both from a technical and an ethical point of view. Keep in mind though that discussion/primarily opinon based questions are discouraged so make sure you have an actual problem with server stuff you need a solution for.

Comment: @rene Oh wow, there's a separate _meta_ area for ServerFault! I learn something new every day. [Asked](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6211/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-on-setting-up-a-torrent-server).

Comment: @Nickolai There's actually one for each site! Try meta.writers, meta.rpg, meta.superuser...