# What is the Stack Exchange community's stance on digital anonymity?

Tags: discussion, ethics

Although I understand the site hosts information and that information in itself should not be censored, looking at tor.stackexchange.com it seems that a sizeable number of questions are related to using privacy for nefarious purposes.

While tor, bit-torrent, etc have legal use-cases in themselves, I would argue that these and similar tools are far more often used for breaking the law than 
with legal intentions.

And with some of the information that tor.stackexchange makes available, technically Stack Exchange is facilitating illegal activity. (Though I should mention that I would struggle to do without the Stack Exchange network in general).

For example:

1. [Why aren't the biggest bittorrent file sharing sites using Tor yet?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14727/why-arent-the-biggest-bittorrent-file-sharing-sites-using-tor-yet)
2. [Using Torrent via Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/727/using-torrent-via-tor)
3. [How can BitTorrent traffic be anonymized with Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/64/how-can-bittorrent-traffic-be-anonymized-with-tor)
4. [By pass proxy server for utorrent](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3293/by-pass-proxy-server-for-utorrent) (this is a college kid *probably* asking how to steal movies/music/etc, and receiving an answer; unless they actually mean legal files available over bit-torrent and nowhere else)
5. [Is it possible to use BitTorrent over Tor without harming the network?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11695/is-it-possible-to-use-bittorrent-over-tor-without-harming-the-network)

Considering questions like the above and more, what is Stack Exchange's stance on digital anonymity if one can assume that such anonymity will be used at least to *some* extent (with questions like the above definitely indicating to a *larger* extent) for illegal activity?

Also, considering that sites like Stack Exchange enable people to be anonymous digitally, SE should definitely have a stance!

Comment: You're asking SE, the company, right? Not SE the community?

Comment: I would say I'm asking the community, since it's community moderated

Comment: although... does the company moderate the content at all? then I'm asking the company...

Comment: It is your question, make up your mind. Yes, the community moderates. SE staff facilitates and is the ultimate gatekeeper for any moderation disputes and they decide on the general direction the sites are heading. I don't mind if you would include all parties but atm it is unclear who you expect to answer.

Comment: Then maybe you should have a look at [chemistry.se] also and [security.se], there's information usable to create threats there too...

Comment: My point being: everyone is responsible of their own action, teaching someone how to do something is not the problem or any martial art or security information teacher would be in troubles at a point as 'facilitating illegal activity' in some way

Comment: Related: [Did SE assist in the apprehension of Ross Ulbricht?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199353/did-the-stack-exchange-staff-members-assist-in-the-apprehension-of-ross-ulbricht)

Comment: Related: [Ethics of a BitTorrent Software Proposal in Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210790/162704)

Comment: "assume that such anonymity will be used at least to some extent (with questions like the above definitely indicating to a larger extent) for illegal activity?" - If the community does it's job correctly, we make remove the reference to the illegal activity in the question, and make it broad enough where useful answer can be submitted.  "his is a college kid probably asking how to steal movies/music/etc" - **Or it is a guy who wants to bypass a proxy server, which by the way, isn't illegal.**

Comment: I don't see anything in any of those questions that indicates anything nefarious

Comment: downloading movies and series that you haven't explicitly purchased is illegal @Cai. Asking how to bypass a proxy server so that you can use bit-torrent isn't in itself nefarious. but such a question is most probably geared towards finding out how to steal music/movies/software/etc, which is nefarious

Comment: @ZachSmith - downloading movies and series that you haven't explicitly purchased is illegal **in certain jurisdictions**. Not everywhere.

Comment: Asking how to bypass a proxy server, @ZachSmith may be because you live under a restrictive regime where you can't even read certain websites because they are blocked. Assumptions.

Comment: We live in a big strange world, where there are a lot of differences in culture, how the state operates and more. Don't paint all users in the brush of your culture and experience.

Comment: Could this be the most disliked post on the stackexchange network??? seems like it should be closed then....

Answer (score 6):

You are making assumptions - and the fact is that there are a lot of valid reasons why someone would want to use Tor (and not for nefarious/illegal/immoral reasons).

That out of the way, lets think about code. As in - programming. A piece of code can be used to build a bot net. Or a virus. Or a trojan.

Perhaps we should disallow questions about code on Stack Overflow?

Just because a tool (tor/code/hammer/whatever) **can** be used for illegal activities doesn't mean much, so long as the usual usage is not illegal.

Comment: I would say that the normal usage of certain tools is illegal (bit-torrent). Although these tools are useful in a legal way. Certain questions are geared towards illegal usage, that is all I'm saying

Comment: I would add to your answer that even the US department of State was a big sponsor of Tor (https://www.torproject.org/about/sponsors.html.en)

Comment: @ZachSmith - certain questions *may* be geared towards that. But that could also be your bias speaking, rather than the meaning of the asker. When I have witnessed questions (on Stack Overflow) that were obviously for spam/cracking, the community was fairly vocal in rejecting them (downvotes, closure and deletion). I am just saying - don't assume bad intentions where there may be other things in play.

Comment: @ZachSmith There are legitimate uses for bittorrent, for example downloading libreoffice - they provide a torrent download.

Comment: @DavidPostill - he's not saying there aren't legitimate uses. He does claim that most usages are pirating.